Why doesn’t First Order Logic follow Natural Language and Connexive logic?
Why doesn’t First Order Logic follow Natural Language and Connexive logic? I ask because of the following:
Consider the statement: If all Xs are cats, then all Xs are mammals. Following natural language, I would depict the statement as ∀x(Cx)→∀x(Mx). I would also depict the negation of this statement as ∀x(Cx)→∃x(¬Mx), which would translate to if all Xs are cats then some Xs are not mammals. Or consider the following false statement: if all Xs are mammals, then all Xs are cats. I would depict it as ∀x(Mx)→∀x(Cx). I would also depict the negation as ∀x(Mx)→∃x(¬Cx). It also seems that we don’t need Modus Ponens in these depictions. But I could be wrong.

FOL is a simplified model of human language suitable mainly for formalizing mathematical reasoning. There are many other more complex formalisms more apt to track the complexity of human language.

I think you mean classical logic, connexive logics are also first order. And classical logic does not always follow natural language because it is intended to be only a first approximation with transparent technical properties. Natural language has too many inconsistencies, redundancies and idiosyncrasies for that. But "if all Xs are cats, then all Xs are mammals" will be translated into classical logic just as you wrote. If you meant it to be ∀x(Cx → Mx) then it has to be rephrased even in the natural language, as "all cats are mammals", say.

@Conifold, also, classical logic doesn't assume that the all X as in all X are cats is the same X as in all X are mammals. Also, why do we need to use Modus Ponens in a conditional, especially if the antecedent is contingent?

Classical logic does assume that, quantification is taken over the same domain even when different variables are used, as in "if all Xs are cats, then all Ys are mammals". Unless, of course, you intend "X" as something other than a faceless label, but then you will have to spell that out even in the natural language. And we do not use modus ponens in a conditional, we use modus ponens to infer conclusion from the conditional.

I understand your question to be that you are aware that first order classical logic is the most commonly used logic, and you are asking why it is not more common to use connexive logic instead.
As you are also no doubt aware, the main difference lies in the fact that classical logic makes use of the material conditional, which differs from the conditional of connexive logic. If we use → for the connexive conditional, then A → B and A → ¬B are contraries, and so from A → ¬B we can deduce ¬(A → B). This differs from the material conditional ⊃ where A ⊃ B and A ⊃ ¬B are consistent and jointly entail ¬A.
The short answer is that classical logic provides a better fit with what is desired in a logic for use in mathematics and science. The material conditional is a truth function and so it works well together with the other truth functional connectives of classical logic. The classical concept of logical consequence is a bare notion of necessary truth preservation. Material conditionals and classical logical consequence do not attempt to capture more complex relationships.
Conditionals that occur in natural languages are often referred to under the categories of indicative conditionals and counterfactual conditionals. In general, these do not behave like material conditionals and there have been many attempts to devise logics for them. Connexive logic is one of those. It is motivated by the desire to have a conditional that expresses a stronger connection between the antecedent and consequent of a conditional than just truth preservation. This motivation is also shared by modal logics and by the family of relevance logics.
I am not entirely convinced by your example, but there is an abundance of similar examples where the material conditional does not fit. Consider:

If John has typhoid then John is healthy.

This is false. But suppose we represent it as a material conditional:

John has typhoid ⊃ John is healthy

Then this being false entails that John has typhoid and John is not healthy. Clearly the conditional being false should not entail that its antecedent is true. This would be a better fit for a connexive conditional, since the negation of

John has typhoid → John is healthy

gives instead

John has typhoid → ¬ (John is healthy)

We might also use a strict conditional here instead. When negated this yields the weaker

It is possible that John has typhoid and is not healthy.

Graham Priest offers another example as follows:

It is not the case that if there is a good God then the prayers of the wicked are answered.

If this is a material conditional, then it entails the existence of a good God. Clearly we cannot prove the existence of God this easily. A connexive conditional would fit here, or again a strict conditional or maybe a variably strict conditional.
But there is price to pay for these more complex conditionals. They are more difficult to evaluate. In the interests of simplicity, it is often helpful to keep the logic as straightforward as possible.

You seem to be misunderstanding the way that quantification works. What do you mean when you say "if all Xs are cats"? What is an X? Since you don't restrict what an X is, it can be anything, so "if all Xs are cats" means "if everything in the universe is a cat", and your example becomes

If everything in the universe is a cat, then everything in the universe is a mammal.

Now, that statement is true enough, and your translation ∀x(Cx)→∀x(Mx) is fine. However, that's probably not what you meant to say because the premise ∀x(Cx) is false. Everything in the universe is not a cat. What you mean is probably something more like this:

Let X be any class of objects. Then if every X is a cat, then every X is a mammal.

This isn't something that translates directly to predicate logic; it's more like set theory:

for all X, if X is a subset of cat then X is a subset of mammal.

But what you are probably really trying to get at is something more like this:

All cats are mammals.

This would translate to the predicate logic ∀x(Cx→Mx).
